# Passing variables to Tkinter geometry method

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying for a while now to find out if there is a way to pass variables to the `geometry` method in Tkinter.

I know the `geometry` method accepts a string:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200X1024")
```

I want to open the window based in the screen width.

```
root = Tk()
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

What I've tried is this:

```
geometry = "%dX%d" % (w,h)
root.geometry(geometry)
```

or

```
root.geometry(("%dX%d" % (w,h)))
```

No matter how I concatenate the variables it gives this error:

```
TlcError: bad geometry specifier "1280X1024"
```

So is it possible to pass variables to the `geometry` method?

Comment: Had you *tried* your first example, you'd see the problem...

Comment: I did try it actually but thanks for the info

Comment: @jonrsharpe next time you feel like being "helpful" you should consider that fact that someone did try all of their examples and just didn't see something as minor as an uppercase letter being a huge difference in the code running or not.

Comment: @MGHandy You could instead ask the right question. Passing variables is _not at all_ related to the error you're having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Tk.geometry` method is not very "smart" when it comes to interpreting the string you give it.  Instead, it requires you to specify the window size exactly as:

```
<width>x<height>
```

Meaning, your uppercase `X` is confusing it.  Simply change `X` to `x` and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
#works for python 3.4

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
screen_resolution = str(screen_width)+'x'+str(screen_height)

window.geometry(screen_resolution)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the code using brackets with string format() function:

```
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(window_width, window_height))
```

As well as set its x and y location properties concatenating with "+":

```
window.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x-coord, y-coord))
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to do anything that complex just do:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x200") #taking x=500 and y=200 for example
```

Comment: You didn't read the question, that's exactly what the author doesn't want to do.