# While executing the below code getting an error bad geometry specifier in python

Tags: python, tkinter

While trying the below code:

```
import tkinter

print(tkinter.TkVersion)

print(tkinter.TclVersion)

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()

mainWindow.title("Hello Python")

mainWindow.geometry("1200X1024")

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I am getting an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Satya\IdeaProjects\GUO_python\tkinter1.py", line 11, in <module>
     mainWindow.geometry("1200X1024")
   File "C:\Users\Satya\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1835, in wm_geometry
     return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
 _tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "1200X1024"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJyn6.jpg

Comment: I'm struggling to find the attached screenshot :P

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJyn6.jpg

Comment: Nice screenshot. Please add your code and the error to the actual question.

Comment: Hope this time it is fine..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variables to Tkinter geometry method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574854/passing-variables-to-tkinter-geometry-method)

Answer (score 3):

The arguments you passed to geometry aren't quite right.

You have written `1200X1024` - but that `X` needs to be lowercased.

Try `mainWindow.geometry("1200x1024")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also add "+" to specify where you want your window to position on your screen

> `("1200x1024+100+10")`

```
import tkinter

print(tkinter.TkVersion)

print(tkinter.TclVersion)

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()

mainWindow.title("Hello Python")

mainWindow.geometry("1200x1024") # use "x" instead of " X"

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you set `1200x1024` (and not 'X') to make your window taking your whole screen you can use `mainWindow.state('zoomed')`

Comment: your answer assumes that the physical display is 1200x1024. If you have any other sized screen, the two are not equivalent.